# How can I load the page before PHP starts creating an archive of photos?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, asynchronous

I'm trying to allow users to create an archive of photos located on the server side and download this archive without waiting in the meantime on a white page without knowing whats happening until PHP finishes to execute.

I've got a list of photos inside an html form on say index.html.

```
    <form action="include/download_archive.php" method="POST" id="downloadForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="downloadForm" value="downloadForm">
        <ul id="photos">
//JavaScript populates this list with photos once the document is ready.
        </ul>
    </form>
```

There is also a button that triggers a javascript function which submits the form.

```
document.getElementById('downloadForm').submit();
```

On the PHP page (say download_archive.php) that processes the form submission, I'm reading the array of images, creating an archive and then providing with a download link to the archive.

```
if(isset($_POST['downloadForm']) && $_POST['downloadForm']=="downloadForm"){
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        ini_set('max_input_vars','500000' );
        set_time_limit(0);
        //Checking if the zip already exists and remove it
        if(file_exists('../collections/Zips/'.$collection.'.zip'))
            unlink('../collections/Zips/'.$collection.'.zip');
        //Get the array of images
        $images = $_POST['images'];
        //Push the images into a new array with the correct path
        foreach($images as $image => $value) {
            array_push($files, "../collections/".$collection."/".$value);
        }
        //Create a new archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open('../collections/Zips/'.$collection.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
        //Add the files to the archive
        foreach ($files as $file) {
          $zip->addFile($file);
        }
        //Store the relative location to the zip file
        $zipPath = '../collections/Zips/'.$collection.'.zip';
        //If the zip was succesfully closed, echo a download link.
        if($zip->close()){
            $link = BASE_URL2."collections/Zips/".$collection.'.zip';
            $link = str_replace(" ", "%20", $link);
            echo "<a href='".$link."'>Download photos</a>";
        }
```

The main problem is that once I select the photos on the main page and hit the "download" button and the form is being submitted by javascript. I'm bound to wait there, on the main page until the whole PHP script is done and only then I'm redirected to the PHP page.

I thought about having a form on the PHP page which handles the creation of the archive and I would be getting the files array through the main form submission and then when the PHP page has fully loaded, make a fetch api request to the inner form, but I'm having trouble keeping the data throughout these operations(the array of files).

I also thought about asynch PHP, but couldn't find a way to handle that other than socket-way which seems limited.

I believe I'm overcomplicating it, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the script with exec, put it in the background and then take the user to the next page. On this page, you can have ajax check for the script to finish, while the user is given a message or something so they know something is happening. Once the script is complete; your page can then update with a link to download the file.

```
exec('nohup /var/.../script.php > /dev/null 2> /dev/null & echo $!');
```

That will run the script as a background process and your page doesn't need to wait for it.

You can even get the process id when you run it using `$pid = exec($command ,$op);` or `$pid = (int)$op[0];` which you can pass back to your page and have the next page poll for it to finish:

```
$command = 'ps -p '.$pid;

exec($command, $op);

if (! isset($op[1])) {
    // process finished
}
else {
    // still running
}
```

OK - here is my fully working answer:

index.php:

```
<?php
exec('nohup php run.php > /dev/null 2> /dev/null & echo $!', $op);

$pid = (int)$op[0];

header('location: check.php?pid='.$pid);
```

run.php:

```
<?php

sleep(5);
```

check_process.php:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

$pid = $_REQUEST['pid'];

$command = 'ps -p '.$pid;

exec($command, $op);

if (! isset($op[1])) {
    $output = 'script finished';
}
else {
    $output = 'script running';
}

print $output;
```

check.php:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Check</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>

check_process('<?=$_REQUEST['pid']?>');

function check_process(pid) {

    console.log('pid: '+pid);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               if(xmlhttp.responseText == 'script running') {
                   check_process(pid);
               }
               document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "check_process.php?pid="+pid, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Put all these in the same directory and open index.php. It will spawn a background process which, as an example will sleep for five seconds. It will send you to a page where is shows the script is running. When the script dies; it will update the page to tell you it's finished. I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions though.

Comment: I didn't accept the answer yet cause even though it sounds to be working, I haven't managed to use this approach to execute any php script. Do you have any simple example/link to walk me through using this?

Comment: Give me a little while and I'll write a more detailed example and update my answer...

Comment: OK - I've written a fully working example. Let me know if you have any problems.